# gettin a blue screen when sending a KML file to the android emulator

Tags: android, mapping, location, kml, osmdroid

I am developing an android mapping application, using OSMDROID API, I need to get the location of the user once and center the map in that location, I register the current activity to listen to location updates, after the first location is receive, I unregister the listener, the code is

```
//to regiter to locationchanges
locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 3, this); 
//to unregister to updates
locMgr.removeUpdates(this);
```

the code work very fine when I send one location, but If send  a KML file to the emulator, I get a blue screen, and If I press back button and enter the same activity again I find the map centered at one off the locations send in the KML file.
the question is why I am geting this blue screen and would that hepen if I test the app in a real phisical handset???

Answer (score 0):

If you send gps fix from KML file in DDMS, It sends lat \ lon consecutively util KML file end (if you do not control). Please make sure that how did you handle if you get one more gps fix in a seconds. May be blue screen is coming invalid lat / lon. It shows sea on map.

Comment: I don't think that the lat/lon may be invalid because I obtained the KML file using google maps